# Node red httpstatic not working

Tags: node-red

Kinda new to node-red, still puzzling on how to serve the static files

in `setting.js`, i had set the httpstatic to point onto a folder

```
 httpStatic: 'C:\public',
```

in the folder, it contain a file name  `sprite.png`

i had restart node red, and run the testing page which the node have

```
msg.payload = "<html>Test</html><img src=\"sprite.png\"></html>"
return msg;
```

still i hit file not found

```
GET http://localhost:1880/sprite.png 404 (Not Found)
```

what actually goes wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` character in the path:

```
httpStatic: 'C:\\public',
```

Comment: aww man, never thought an escape have that much different, it is working now, will mark as answer, thanks

Comment: For me this didn't work. I had to use forward slashes in the path C:/Users/<username>/.node-red/static